# Cache Service worker for localhost can't be remove and unregistered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, service-worker, development-environment, web-development-server

[image]

Tried to uninstall chrome, uninstall node and so on. But I still get cached and it can't be removed, when I run other projects with the same port without any service worker, I also get cache by this service worker.

Also tried to remove all register service worker, local application and unregister button in application. But I still get this cache

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this caching usually while making a progressive web app, I always turn on disable cache from the network tab. It will prevent the loading of the app from cache memory:
[image]

Please do this and make a hard reload on your app. A hard refresh clears your browser cache for a specific page, which forces it to load the most recent version of that page. To make a hard reload press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try to unregister a ServiceWorker

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(registrations => {
  registrations.forEach(registration => {
    registration.unregister();
  });
});
```